# Joystick's pad is moving mouse cursor

Tags: usb, cursor, gamepad

I have got a pad with 2 analog pads. If I move first one (on the left side) it moves mouse cursor that returns into center of screen. The second one does nothing but moving pad into the right side teleports mouse into the center. This is very annoying especially when I want to play games. I use ubuntu 16.04 if this info is needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked driver compatibility with your gamepad?

If you are looking for a temporary fix, use the following code:
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`
This will disable input to your screen cursor. To turn it back on, enter this :
`sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`